# Access to Remote App requires login to remote Desktop

Tags: desktop, remote, web

I have a remote app (using remote desktop) which I am happy for users to log into. But at the moment, when the user clicks on the link/icon on the web page to activate the app:

•   The Remote App window appears with the message "starting" and the app name

•   Then a Windows security window appears asking for credentials (or allowing him to use another account)

•   he enters the password

•   And then he get the remote desktop where he has to log in again - It seems he can pick any of the accounts

•   Assume he logs in with the same credentials as used in the Windows Security window.

•   The application then starts and the Windows desktop disappears.

If  he shuts down the application and starts it again, the application starts immediately without any windows security or visible desktop logon.

If he then open in a different browser (egg IE instead of FF) he has to go through the windows security, desktop double logon and the second time it goes straight to the web app.

If he shuts down the browser and restarts it he has to go through the double sign in scenario.

Ideally I'd like the user to go through the Windows Security screen and then straight to the app. But any solution that prevents this double log on and more importantly prevent the remote user from having access to the desktop would be a plus.